# Filtering 2 layer array object in immutable way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of objects in following format, which is intended to filter in `immutable way`. Can be done with either `pure javascript`, `es6` or `lodash` library.

Note: The key point here is filter in `immutable way`.

**Logic:**

```
if (all product qty in the first level object is empty string or 0) {
    do not show that first that level object
}

if (product qty is empty string or 0) {
    do not show that product
}
```

**Input:**

```js
 let targetArray = [{
     recipient: '1',
     product: [{
             productId: '1',
             qty: '2'
         }, {
             productId: '2',
             qty: '0'
         }
     ]
 }, {
     recipient: '2',
     product: [{
             productId: '1',
             qty: '0'
         }, {
             productId: '3',
             qty: ''
         }
     ]
 },
 ]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
    {
        recipient: '1',
        product: [{
          productId: '1',
          qty: '2'
        }]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use reduce for that

```js
let targetArray = [
    {
        recipient: '1',
        product: [{
          productId: '1',
          qty: '2'
        }, {
            productId: '2',
            qty: '0'
        }]
    },
   {
        recipient: '2',
        product: [{
          productId: '1',
          qty: '0'
        }, {
            productId: '3',
            qty: ''
        }]
    },
]

let filtered = targetArray.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  let products = curr.product.filter(product => parseInt(product.qty) > 0);
  
  if (products.length === 0) {
    return acc;
  }
  
  acc.push({...curr, product: products});
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log({filtered});
console.log({targetArray});
```